# Qt c++ play sound on key press - stops working after a few seconds

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making an apllication which needs to play .wav file when user type something inside QTextEdit. I made some code but after minute or less the sound stops, so I made silly workarround. After 30 clicks I invoke sound->stop(); and then the loop start again, that works, but it's not good, can you give better solution. Here is my code:

```
int count = 0;
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e){
    if(e->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
       {
        tipka->play();
        tipka->seek(0);
        count++;
        if(count == 30){
            tipka->pause();
            count = 0;
        }
       }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `tipka` variable? Why you filter events on Main window and not getting signals from textEdit? What means `but it's not good`? These are just some of the many unanswered riddles held within this mysterious question.

Comment: tipka is Phonon::MediaObject. I'm filtering events because I found that solution on internet. "but it's not good" means that it's working for couple of seconds and then it stops, then again after 5 or more seconds it start to work and then again it stop etc, so it's not good. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [QSound](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qsound.html).  It doesn't provide any seeking capabilities but it gives you the ability to loop, play, and stop.  It's not feature rich but it gets the job done.

```
QSound sound("File name.wav");
sound.play();
sound.stop();
```

Also, you can use its static function to play a sound.

```
QSound::play("File name.wav");
```

Comment: QSound is not in use anymore, at least on Linux, and btw I'm using Linux

Comment: Sure it is.  Even if you are using [Qt5](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/qsound.html), it is still supported.

Comment: I tried that already but it's not giving any output to speakers, so I googled a little bit and found out that  it's not supported in Qt 4, maybe I'm wrong but that's what I found. And really QSound it's not working, even if I put full path to sound file.

Comment: In the documentation for QSound, it said that it uses "Network Audio System" under X11, if available.  Otherwise all operations work silently.

Comment: that's what I found too. But how to install NAS, and of course, if I want to ship my app to another PC I should also include NAS in my setup file. Am I right?

Comment: so is there any chance for solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and thank me later :)
in your MainWindow constructor -

```
  installEventFilter(this);
```

in header-

```
  protected:
  bool eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent*);
```

in cpp-

```
  bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e){

  Q_UNUSED(o);

  if(e->type() == QEvent::KeyRelease)
    {        player->stop();
            player->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/sounds/button_push.mp3"));
            player->play();
    }
     return false;
   }
```